# MYSQL Join three tables with exceptions

Tags: mysql, exception, join, datatables

I am working with three SQL tables and I am using INNER JOIN to join these tables. Here is an overview of what the tables look like.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
   `id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `firstName` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `lastName` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                                                                       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


CREATE TABLE `Ownership` ( 
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `certificate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `unicity` (`user`,`certificate`)                                              ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 

CREATE TABLE `Certificate` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `domain` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `creationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   
   `expirationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   `type` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                                                                       ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The request to join the tables is the following :

```
select user, lastName, domain 
from Ownership 
    INNER JOIN User ON Ownership.user = User.id 
    INNER JOIN Certificate ON Ownership.certificate = Certificate.id;`
```

I have this type of result for example : 
[image]

What I would like is to retrieve only one user for one domain name and create an exception to do the join only if the certificate.domain value does not already exists.

Is this something possible with MYSQL ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't post table structures as image. We can't copy/paste to do tests.

Comment: Can you provide the sample result you want to get?

Comment: @Cid , I updated the table structures

Comment: @PavelSmirnov  I would like to get the same result with the first or the third line removed, it doesn't matter which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a pre-query to at least qualify some uniqueness component associated with a given domain.  To get that, lets consider this.

```
select 
      C.domain,
      min( O.user ) JustOneUser 
   from 
      Certificate C
         JOIN Ownership O
            on C.ID = O.Certificate
   group by
      C.Domain
```

So this will get one user for a given domain.  Now, use THAT result to get the user associated to the domain.

```
select
      PQ.Domain,
      U.LastName,
      U.FirstName
   from
      (select 
             C.domain,
             min( O.user ) JustOneUser 
          from 
             Certificate C
                JOIN Ownership O
                   on C.ID = O.Certificate
          group by
             C.Domain ) PQ
      JOIN User U
         on PQ.JustOneUser = U.ID
```

Comment: Great! Thank you